# Determining Button State from a separate class

Tags: c#, windows, button, emulation

I am having another issue writing my chip8 Emu. I have managed to get all instructions working aside from those that require input or those that involve graphics.

I am trying to write a seperate class to simply determine whether a button is being pressed or not. I have been working on this for some time and I think that I must be missing something very simple or I do not understand something conceptually. Here is the class I am writing with the exact errors in the comments

```
using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class userIn
{
    bool pressed = false;
    public userIn()
    {

    }

    public bool checkPress() //Error    9   'WindowsFormsApplication1.userIn.checkPress()': not all code paths return a value   C

    {  //<---- it is teling me that a closing bracket is expected here?
         private void key5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
             pressed = true;
    }

    private void keyb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pressed = true;
    }

    private void key0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pressed = true;
    }

    private void keya_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pressed = true;
    }

    private void keye_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pressed = true;
    }

    private void key9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pressed = true;
    }

    private void key8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pressed = true;
    }

    private void key7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pressed = true;
    }

    private void keyd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pressed = true;
    }

    private void keyf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pressed = true;
    }

    private void key6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pressed = true;
    }

    private void key4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pressed = true;
    }

    private void keyc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pressed = true;
    }

    private void key3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pressed = true;
    }

    private void key2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pressed = true;
    }

    private void key1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pressed = true;
    }


        return pressed; //Error 6   Invalid token 'return' in class, struct, or interface member declaration    

    }
}
```

} //  Error 8   Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

Last line would not fit in the box

Does anyone have any Ideas or suggestions?

As always any help is appreciated!

Comment: Fix your indentation and you'll see the problem immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`}` for `checkPress` method comes in end of class, your correct method:

```
public bool checkPress()
{ 
    return pressed; 
}
```

and your code should be like this:

```
using System;
...

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class userIn
    {
        bool pressed = false;
        public userIn()
        {

        }

        public bool checkPress() // This method
        {
            return pressed;
        } // Must close here, not end of class

        .
        . 
        .

        private void key1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pressed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a button is belong to class `XXX` then you can expose its state by create a read-only property. It is not a good idea to create another class that depends on internal-implementation of `XXX`.

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer:

You have opened a method inside of another method.

---

### Long answer

The following is your code properly indented (I recomend you AStyle for that):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class userIn
    {
        bool pressed = false;
        public userIn()
        {

        }

        public bool checkPress() //Error    9   'WindowsFormsApplication1.userIn.checkPress()': not all code paths return a value   C
        {  //<---- it is teling me that a closing bracket is expected here?
            private void key5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                pressed = true;
            }

            private void keyb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                pressed = true;
            }

            private void key0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                pressed = true;
            }

            private void keya_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                pressed = true;
            }

            private void keye_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                pressed = true;
            }

            private void key9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                pressed = true;
            }

            private void key8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                pressed = true;
            }

            private void key7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                pressed = true;
            }

            private void keyd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                pressed = true;
            }

            private void keyf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                pressed = true;
            }

            private void key6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                pressed = true;
            }

            private void key4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                pressed = true;
            }

            private void keyc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                pressed = true;
            }

            private void key3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                pressed = true;
            }

            private void key2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                pressed = true;
            }

            private void key1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                pressed = true;
            }
            return pressed; //Error 6   Invalid token 'return' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
        }
    }
} // Error 8 Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
```

Are you still unable to see the problem? Ok, here is a condensed version:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class userIn
    {
        bool pressed = false;
        public userIn()
        {

        }

        public bool checkPress() //Error    9   'WindowsFormsApplication1.userIn.checkPress()': not all code paths return a value   C
        {  //<---- it is teling me that a closing bracket is expected here?
            private void key5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                pressed = true;
            }

            //And some other methods

            return pressed; //Error 6   Invalid token 'return' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
        }
    }
} // Error 8 Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
```

Does it look right to you?

Well, it just a way to put it, here is what the compiler sees:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class userIn
    {
        bool pressed = false;
        public userIn()
        {

        }

        public bool checkPress() //Error    9   'WindowsFormsApplication1.userIn.checkPress()': not all code paths return a value   C
        {  //<---- it is teling me that a closing bracket is expected here?
            private void key5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                pressed = true;
        }

        //And some other methods

        return pressed; //Error 6   Invalid token 'return' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
    }
}
} // Error 8 Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
```

Does it make sense now?

Chances are that you think the above code is right, if so this is not an answer... instead it is a question: **What do you think you are trying to do?**

Ok, yes, C# supports lambdas, are you trying to do the following?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class userIn
    {
        bool pressed = false;
        public userIn()
        {

        }

        public bool checkPress()
        {

            key5.Click += (sender, e)  =>
            {
                pressed = true;
            };

            //And some other (anonymous) methods

            return pressed;
        }
    }
}
```

But my instinct says that you just did some weird copy-paste and the intended code was like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class userIn
    {
        bool pressed = false;
        public userIn()
        {

        }

        public bool checkPress()
        {               
            return pressed;
        }

        private void key5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pressed = true;
        }

        //And some other methods
    }
}
```

Make sense? I hope.